# whats the difference between these two in django?

Tags: python, django

I am new in django and wondering what is the difference between

```
{{ something }}
```

and

```
{% something %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ expression }}

{% tag %}
```

Expressions will be evaluated, and the string representation will be inserted into the document. Tags will simply be evaluated.

You would do well to read the full explanation, with examples, in [django docs on templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/).

EDIT: changed "statement" to the more correct "tag"

Comment: This is not the correct answer. `{% %}` does not allow arbitrary statements; it is for template tags only.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I agree; I messed up on terminology, forgetting they call them "tags".

Answer (score 2):

`{{ something }}` -- this evaluates expression `something` and puts the result into the template.

`{% something %}` -- this is a template language tag (statement) -- one of the [defined ones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/).

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ something }} -- something is a variable  which hold value

{% something %} is like bulitin  template tags like if,else, for, custom tags etc
```